# Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/5cxxxx

Tags: usb, filesystem

I'm trying to move my root partition onto a SSD. It is a PI1. I know the Pi(1 and 2, at least) cannot boot directly from USB (and I'm not interested in doing that anyway, I would only load the filesystem onto SSD after boot).

So I want use "old secure method": boot from SD and filesystem into SSD/USB/whatever can be not the SD anymore.

I followed all the instructions [here](http://www.kupply.com/move-your-raspberry-pi-system-to-usb-in-10-steps/) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177).

The result is, during boot an emergency lock occurs:

```
Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/5cxxxx
Dependency failed for /boot
Dependency failed for Local File System
```

I have tried several methods on `/etc/fstab` you can see from the comments:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=5c1ec57d-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
#PARTUUID=5c1ec57d-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
#/dev/disk/by-uuid/76929594-b034-4599-8f31-34af1ae2ff79 /       ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
#PARTUUID=7F58C5CF-67B0-4868-A46F-73D87718DA4E  /       ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/76929594-b034-4599-8f31-34af1ae2ff79  /       ext4    defaults,noatime        0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
tmpfs   /tmp/log        tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=50M 0 0ù
```

This is my `cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7f58c5cf-67b0-4868-a46f-73d87718da4e rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

And at the end of `config.txt` I added:

```
program_usb_timeout=1
```

Of course `PARTUUID` and `UUID` are correct, (I copy and pasted these directly).

Comment: Following 5 year old tutorials for an obsolete OS is not recommended.

Comment: 2nd tutorial, on the bottom, is updated to 1 year ago : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177

Comment: To clarify what you have include the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (replace sda by the device used)

Answer (score 0):

The Pi **CAN** boot directly from USB (at least Pi3)

You should have `root=PARTUUID=5c1ec57d-02` - the bootloader doesn't know what to do with a UUID

You are not mounting the partition (it is commented out in fstab)
`#PARTUUID=5c1ec57d-02  /`

PS The above assumes you have copied the root partition to SSD before booting.
PPS You can use a SSD, but it won't be any faster than a HDD as the USB2 interface limits speed.

Comment: @Darth Vader edited my post. My is PI1 and I'm not interested in booting directly from USB. The line which you referrer is the original commented, root on uSD. I'm mounting the partition from `/dev/disk/by-uuid/76929594-b034-4599-8f31-34af1ae2ff79`

And yes, before booting I copied entire `/` onto SSD.

Comment: For the record I am opposed to the editing of questions (other than to remove offensive remarks) and CERTAINLY not deleting information. You should enter your Pi details (preferably in a tag "The PI is the first model" is ambiguous - this would imply a Pi model A). At this stage I really don't know what you have in your files. `/dev/disk/by-uuid/76929594-b034-4599-8f31-34af1ae2ff79` has nothing to do with mount or fstab.